# Default value for a block argument

Tags: ruby

I would like to create a method which accepts a block argument but defaults the block to a method that always returns true.

```
def my_method(&print_if = Proc.new { true })
  internal_value = [1, 2, 3]
  puts "printing" if print_if.call(internal_value)
end

my_method { |array| array[1] == 2 }
 "printing"
 => nil
my_method { |array| array[1] == 3 }
 => nil
my_method
 "printing"
 => nil
```

It seems that my best option is to check for the presence of a block in the method. This works, its just clunkier

```
def my_method(&print_if)
  internal_value = [1, 2, 3]
  puts "printing" if !block_given? || print_if.call(internal_value)
end

my_method { |array| array[1] == 2 }
 "printing"
 => nil
my_method { |array| array[1] == 3 }
 => nil
my_method
 "printing"
 => nil
```

Any way to default a block arg in Ruby? Please no answers that rely on external libraries (even Rails), just trying to find out if this is possible with pure Ruby.

Comment: You can also do (with your second) example `print_if ||= -> { true }`

Comment: I just noticed your second code block, after posting my answer (since deleted), but there is nothing wrong with that at all, as the code describes perfectly what you are trying to achieve. I personally think `print_if.nil? ? true : print_if.call(internal_value)` reads better.

Comment: @Sergio, what are you talking about?

Comment: Remember that declaring a block as an argument carries a fairly hefty performance penalty as Ruby needs to capture a lot of contextual information for a block that's able to be passed on. Whenever possible use `block_given?` and `yield` in conjunction. For light use the difference is largely academic, but for performance sensitive code the difference can be dramatic. The general rule is to only declare block parameters if you need to forward the block to another method, in which case you have to pay the price anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this dirty hack:

```
def my_method(print_if = -> (*args) { block_given? ? yield(*args) : true })
  internal_value = [1, 2, 3]
  puts "printing" if print_if.call(internal_value)
end
```

But is it convenient?

Comment: I think this answer is pretty good in the sense that it proves Ruby does not have a good way of setting defaults on arguments that should be procs/lambdas/blocks. I am not the biggest fan in general of the way Ruby allows passing around methods, but such is life. Just wanted to see if there was a shortcut I was missing.